# IntelliJ IDEA - How to reattach Variables Tab to be side by side with Debug Tab?

Tags: intellij-idea

Am new to IntelliJ IDEA (am using 2017.1.3)...

By accident when I was debugging a sample unit test, I accidentally detached the Debugger's Variables tab from the entire IDE - its floating now. Is there a way to reattach this to be at the bottom and side by side of the Debug tab (like it used to be)? I tried a bunch of different approaches and when I hit my breakpoint it still floats (like a modal) outside IntelliJ IDEA. Can IntelliJ's views be customized (kind of like Eclipse's Perspectives and Views)? It seems like JetBrains calls views: tabs and calls Perspective: active window. Is IDEA customizable like Eclipse?

Attached is a screenshot of my plight...

[image]

Comment: Please do not squeeze two questions into one. Ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry, the only reason I did was because I didn't want some to harass me saying that I posted duplicates. I will revert my changes and create a new post. Thank you.

Comment: Oh! @Arkadiy, I see you already reverted my post! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the window frame, grab the **tab** that says "Variables" with your mouse. Drag it into the debugger panel.

[image: The X marks the spot]

Comment: Arkadily, thanks! That worked... However, I have some additional questions so I'll edit my answer and post's title above.

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover - at SO we normally do not post "thank you" comments. Mark the answer as "accepted" to express your appreciation :)